# Is it haram for people to act as Prophets?

Tags: halal-haram

In a film called Kingdom Of Solomon( which is about the Prophet Sulayman AS), a actor is portraying Prophet Sulayman. Is this haram because it is haram to act as Prophet Muhammad (Islamic films about Prophet Muhammad don't have someone acting as him as it is haram)?

Comment: The fact is we are encouraged to act upon the Prophet’s PBUH Sunnah. In many cases it’s an OBLIGATION to act like him PBUH. I always find it aggravating when some scholars state that it’s impermissible because of indirect ahadith that they try to use as assumptive evidence. Movies, TV shows are great tools of mass persuasion & dawah. Imagine the Ummah’s state if we had movies, TV shows that depicted these great men as the men that they were, not as some mythical creatures that should never be depicted, but instead we have Turkish/Egyptian soap operas and a bunch of crap. May Allah guide us.

Answer (score 2):

[Al-Azhar University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Azhar_University) prepared ***The Response*** (available in [pdf](http://www.fixyourdeen.com/TheResponse-EN.pdf) and at fixyourdeen.com), and its Question 102 addresses this problem, claiming it is forbidden:

> **Question**: A question was asked regarding playing the role of the Prophet
>   (upon him be peace) and/or the Companions [in a dramatic production].
>
> **Response**:
>   It is good to retell the Qur’anic religious stories through the ways and language
>   of the time. Doing so brings the time of the Prophet to life in the minds of our
>   children. The personalities of the Prophet (upon him be peace) and the
>   messengers of God are so precious and noble that they **must not be played by
>   actors**, and may not be imitated by Satan.

*The Response* contests intolerant legal opinions, so their opinions tend to be "gentle".  However, in this case, they consider acting as a Prophet as haram (mostly concurring with the "intolerant" opinion).

They derive this opinion from the hadith:

> Who ever sees me (in a dream) then he indeed has seen the truth, as Satan cannot appear in my shape.
>   <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 6997](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/91/16)</sub>

From this they continue:

> ... the legal implications of this ensure that it is prohibited for a human to enact (yataqamas) the character of the Prophet (upon him be peace).
>
> If this is the correct legal stance regarding the validity of acting the role of the Seal of Prophets, then the same [prohibition] should apply to playing the parts of God’s previous messengers. ...

Comment: It’s almost baffling that such argumentation is never refuted by other scholars. How in the world do these teachers go from Satan unable to deceive the dreamer as the Prophet - to - its haram for people to act as the Prophet PBUH. Subhana’Allah

Answer (score -2):

I'm not a scholar and I dont know the religious point of view on this but one important thing is that we remember the historic characters as the people who acts which is two serious problem.

1. Those people generally don't represent the "historic figures". How can anybody be able to represent sahaba (Abu Bakr, Omar b Khattab, Uthman, Ali radiallahu anhum), the prophets let alone prophet Mohammad pbuh. If those people are "played" by others, the audience will associate actors/actresses with those big names. Consider, prophet Yusuf was acted by a someone who is okay in terms of beauty, so you decrease the beauty of prophet Yusuf.
2. The next roles or the real life of those people will cause a confusion or misjudgements in people's mind (This is not very obvious). For example, someone played a prophet and then he played in a "dirty/sinful movie"; this might lead people to have wrong associations of the sin to the prophet he played.

We have a saying: `Things can be represented by its equivalent`, if you want to represent a prophet, find a prophet to play him.

Comment: So someone acting as a murderer should be a real life murderer?

Answer (score -3):

In Islam drawing sketches or taking photos of People is forbidden for a valid reason that people out of sheer devotion should not start worshipping such sketches, pictures or sculptures etc. Photos making for valid reasons such as passport, visas or similar inevitable necessities, however, is not haram. Islam does not impose unnecessary hardships on its adherents. It has been declared in Qura'an as well in Hadith. The glaring example, validating this apprehension is well reflected in the case of Jesus Christ (PBUH), Who is being called god, son of god and one-in-three etc. He is being even worshiped by some as a god.

Making movies and acting in them as a character could be done without making a replica of either of the prophets. As this experiment has been done successfully. Islam, in the panoply of Divine religions, by far, is the most logical and far-sighted religion. Some of its injunctions; which used to sound bit strange till yesterday, seem to be making more sense than ever before. The Best Example is that of the Human conception in the mother's womb. Its detailed explanation has baffled medical scientists of today. Thanks
shakir2.wordpress.com

Comment: What is your source fir taking picture? I'd like to hear hadith and verse. Your example of womb doesn't have any relationship with the question

Comment: It is a matter of common sense. You will not find direct mention of a polaroid camera in Qura'an or a Hadith on taking pictures by cell phone, as these things were not available then. such inferences, therefore are deduced from the overall permissibility or impermissibility of things in question. Thanks

Comment: Have you met someone who worshipped cartoons?

Comment: Sorry! I answer questions only on Quora.com